# Trying to fix Steam on Linux Mint 19.1 after X Error

Tags: linux-mint, steam, steam-os

I am trying to run Steam on Linux Mint 19.1, and I get the following error when I attempt to run through the command line:

```
Running Steam on linuxmint 19.1 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
[2019-04-23 21:35:50] Startup - updater built Apr 16 2019 21:00:51
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

My relevant system specs are as follows:
System:
Kernel: 4.15.0-47-generic x86_64 
bits: 64 
compiler: gcc v: 7.3.0 
Desktop: Cinnamon 4.0.10 
wm: muffin 
dm: LightDM 
Distro: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa

Graphics:
Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics 
vendor: Gigabyte 
driver: i915 
v: kernel 
bus ID: 00:02.0 
chip ID: 8086:0412 
Device-2: NVIDIA 
GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] 
vendor: ASUSTeK 
driver: nvidia 
v: 390.116 
bus ID: 01:00.0 
chip ID: 10de:1380 
Display: x11 
server: X.Org 1.19.6 
driver: modesetting,nvidia 
unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
OpenGL: 
renderer: GeForce GTX 750 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 
v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.116 
direct render: Yes 
base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic

I'm not sure if it helps to mention this, but I first encountered the problem earlier today when I installed the NVIDIA 390 driver. Any help in fixing this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: The Nvidia drivers are likely to have been installed with errors.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's possible, since I followed the instructions exactly. While I understand that some sort of error has occurred, I am wondering if anyone has any insight on how to fix it.

Comment: Purge the drivers and reinstall making sure you're selecting the recommended version for your specific Nvidia chip. That's the only "insight" can give at the moment.